# How to add a view inside an UITableView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, ios5

While in the Interface Builder, it's pretty easy to add an `UIView` to an `UITable` and show it correctly, just drag and drop and it's done. But now that's gonna be optional, so it has to be placed programmatically.

Here's how it looked like in the interface builder:
[image: How it looked like in the Interface Builder]

When I added the new view as a subview, it showed on top of the `UITableView`-content, but the content should have some offset. I tried it with the following code:

```
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -140, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.tableView addSubview:self.scrollView];
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(140,0,0,0)];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -140) animated:NO];
```

That seemed to work, it shows correctly.. But when I scroll down, the section header stays at 140 pixels from the top. So I guess I'm using the wrong approach, but have absolutely no idea how to fix it. Could anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I feel really stupid. After hours of trying, I thought of something.. Just checked the source of the .xib file and compared the one with the subview with the one without. The following things showed up:

- The `UIView` was part a subview of the `UITableView`.
- The following reference was added: `<reference key="IBUITableHeaderView" ref="204195654"/>`.

So, changed the code to this:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:self.scrollView];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.scrollView];
```

And it works!

Comment: You mean you automatically turn view you added to the tableView.HeaderView?

Comment: Had to set the `tableHeaderView` property to my header view. Don't know if the `addSubview:` is needed, it's possible that it isn't needed.